# Shopify API request

Tags: javascript, api, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to access the Shopify backend to update a customer's email, phone, and name using vanilla JS. the request is returning successfully but the actual values are not changed.
created a custom app for my store and followed the documentation to get access to api for shopify

HTML:

```
<div class="container with_background">
  <form action="" method="" id="updateCustomerForm" class="page-width">
    
    
    <div class="input-wrapper form-row --100">
      <label for="AddressFirstName">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="address[id]" id="customerId" value="{{customer.id}}" autocapitalize="words" disabled style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" name="address[first_name]" id="customerFirstName" value="{{customer.first_name}}" autocapitalize="words">
    </div>  

    <div class="input-wrapper form-row --100">
      <label for="AddressLastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="address[Last_name]" id="customerLarstName" value="{{customer.last_name}}" autocapitalize="words">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper form-row --100">
      <label for="AddressEmail">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="address[Email_address]" id="customerEmail" value="{{customer.email}}" autocapitalize="words">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper form-row --100">
      <label for="AddressPhone">Mobile Number</label>
      <input type="tel" name="address[Phone]" id="customerPhone" value="{{customer.phone}}">
    </div>
          <button  type="submit" id="saveCustomerToggle" class="btn btn--logout tablinks">Save</button>  

  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("updateCustomerForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){    
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
  let custID = document.getElementById("customerId").value  ;
  let custFN = document.getElementById("customerFirstName").value  ;
  let custLN = document.getElementById("customerLarstName").value  ;
  let custEM = document.getElementById("customerEmail").value  ;
  let custPH = document.getElementById("customerPhone").value  ;
  
  
  console.log(custFN);
  
  let  customerdata = {
    "customer": {
      "customer.id": custID,
      "customer.first_name": custFN ,
      "customer.last_name": custLN,
      "customer.email": custEM,
      "customer.phone": custPH,
    }
  };

  console.table(customerdata);

  let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("updateCustomerForm"));
  console.log(formData);
  const xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xhr.open('PUT', "https://{api_key}:{api_password}@{store}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/customers/" + {{customer.id}} +".json", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(customerdata));
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("1");
        console.log(formData);       
        console.table(customerdata);

      } else {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("2");
                        console.log(formData);

      }
    } else {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log("3");
                      console.log(formData);

    }
  };
```

any idea why it's returning true but it's not taking action for the actual values?

Comment: That code will expose your api password to the world. This doesn’t seem a request they should happen client side.

Comment: I will double down on what @AlexanderStaroselsky said. Shopify admin API credentials with write permissions should NEVER be exposed to the front-end. This is a huge security risk and you can get into hot waters if you are doing this for a client. Please consider using an application or writing a custom one.

Comment: what do you mean by happen client-side? can I have a little explanation please ? also, what app do you recommend to do that? any sugg?

Comment: To protect the credentials either create a  server/api that proxies the requests to the actual Shopify server. Also could use serverless technologies like lambda. What is meant by client side is requests from a front end application like react/Vue/angular, unless you are using a framework like nextjs or nuxtjs that has ability to make requests on the server to protect credentials. Examine the web dev tools and if you can see the admin creds there, it means it is being exposed to the public.